# Tips in optimizing an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I'll try to phrase this question without making it sound like I am seeking for homework answers (this is just a practice problem for algorithms)

you have an array of numbers where every value can occur at most 2x [1 3 5 2 5 1 2 3]
Examine sums from one value to the other instance of itself (5 + 2 + 5) (2 + 5 + 1 + 2)

Find an algorithm that finds the max of such sum.

I came up with a pretty simple algorithm:

```
iterate through the array (for i=1 to n)
iterate through the remaining array (for j=i+1)
if A[i] == A[j]
    s = 0
    iterate through the values between those two points (for k=i to j)
        s = s + A[k]
    maxVal = max(maxVal,s)
```

What are some steps I can take towards optimizing the algorithm. (or any algorithm for that matter). Obviously this solution is the first that came to mind but I am having trouble envisioning better solutions that would be more efficient.

Edit: For sake of the problem I'll just say all elements are postitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate array of cumulative sums:

```
C[0] = A[0]  
for i = 1 to n  
  C[i] = C[i - 1] + A[i]  
A[1 3 5 2 5 1 2 3]  
C[0 1 4 9 11 16 17 19 22]
```

Use these values when pair found:

```
  Sum(i to j) = C[j] - C[i - 1]
```

**P.S.** Are all elements always positive?

Comment: wow this is really smart! I really wish i had a knack for creative solutions like this. What were some of the first things you considered when trying to optimize my solution? (Trying to improve my optimization skills)

Comment: If you can use additional memory, look also at Pham Trung suggestion about hashmap/dusctionary

Comment: @CoderNinja The reduction from infix aggregations to prefix aggregations is a well-known construction in algorithm engineering. Learning this stuff just takes a bit of practice. I can recommend platforms like TopCoder or Codeforces if you want to practice your algorithm/problem solving skills (but it takes effort, there's no free lunch and no simple tips that magically make you solve problems faster).

Comment: @CoderNinja You might notice that initial algorithm calculates almost similar sums (on slightly shifted intervals) again and again.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the most inner loop by pre calculate all the sum from index 1 to index i and store it into an array, call `sum`. So if you want to get the sum between i and j, the result will be sum[j] - sum[i - 1].

```
for(i = 1 to n)
  sum[i] = A[i];
  if(i - 1 > 1)
    sum[i] += sum[i - 1];
```

Also notice that there are only two occurrences for each value in the array, we can remember the first position of this value using a map/dictionary or an array `pos` (if possible) and if we saw it again , we can use it to calculate the sum between the first and this position.

```
  pos[];
  for(i = 1 to n)
     if(pos[A[i]] ==0)
       pos[A[i]] = i;
     else
       result = max(result,sum[i] - sum[pos[A[i]] - 1])
```

So in total, the time complexity of this will be O(n)

Comment: *expected* O(n) ;) Or maybe even O(n) with high probability, depending on the hash table implementation